# Use user snippets inside with VS Code Extension API

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

"I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio Code that allows users to specify their own snippet names in the plugin's settings. The plugin can then use these names to create files.

I've successfully implemented the file creation functionality, but I'm still trying to figure out how to run snippets programmatically.

The following code is not fully tested yet but it illustrates in what context I would like to use the snippet.

```
// user config

 "[extensionName]": [
    ["{folderName}.js", "snippetName1", "JavaScript"],
    ["{folderName}.styled.js", "snippetName2", "JavaScript"],
    ["{folderName}.translation.js", "snippetName3", "JavaScript"]
  ]

// extension.ts

async function createFolder (folderName: string) {
  // Create the folder in the workspace

  const config = await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
  const options: Array<[string, string, string]> = config["[extensionName]"];


  const selectedFolders = await vscode.window.showOpenDialog({
    canSelectFiles: false,
    canSelectFolders: true,
    canSelectMany: false
  });


  if (!selectedFolders || selectedFolders.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const selectedFolderUri = selectedFolders[0];
  const selectedFolderPath = selectedFolderUri.fsPath;
  const folderPath = path.join(selectedFolderPath, folderName);

  await fs.promises.mkdir(folderPath, { recursive: true });


  // Create the files in the folder
  options.forEach(async ([fileName, snippetName, snippetLanguage]: [string, string, string]) => {

    // If the fileName has the variable {folderName}, it will be replaced to the name of the current folder
    const filePath = path.join(folderPath, fileName.replace("{folderName}", folderName));

    const body = ["hello", "world"].join("\n"); // Suppose to be created by snippet

    await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, body);
  });
};
```

Comment: execute the command `editor.action.insertSnippet`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.